# FlatList receiving undefined values after fetching json

Tags: json, react-native, fetch-api, react-native-flatlist

I need to render a `FlatList` after fetching a json containing `connections`. The following piece of code runs correctly but the `travel` object inside the `renderItem` is always `undefined`.

```
import {Text, View, FlatList, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

/**
 * http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=8575201&to=8503000
 */

export function TravelsScreen({navigation}) {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [travels, setTravels] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=8575201&to=8503000')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setTravels(json.connections))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 24}}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={travels}
          renderItem={({travel}) => <Text>Travel: {console.log(travel)}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={travel => travel.from.departureTimestamp.toString()}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your FlatList to :

```
        <FlatList
          data={travels}
          renderItem={({item}) => {console.log(item)}}
          //other properties
        />
```

From [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) the `renderItem` method takes out `item` from the FlatList array and since you are using the `destructuring` syntax to extract it, you should explicitly use `item`. An alternative without the `destructuring` syntax would look like :

```
          <FlatList
          data={travels}
          renderItem={(travel) =>{ console.log(travel.item)}}
          //other properties
        />
```